# Add the store beneath a cms/page in Magento

Tags: magento

In magento I have a cms page called "Shop", which is my shop index page. I want the whole catalog to be 'beneath' this cms page. So my breadcrumbs would be `Home / Shop / <Category>` instead of `Home / <Category>` which is how it is now.

There are probably more ways to do this, and I'm looking for the 'right' way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the  Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs block, you have this :

```
$breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('home', array(
            'label'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Home'),
            'title'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Go to Home Page'),
            'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()
        ));
```

Overwrite this class/method to add your crumb here.

```
$breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('shop', array(
            'label'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Shop'),
            'title'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Your title here'),
            'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()/shop
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you happen to know how I can get the url to be `site.com/shop/category.html` ?

Comment: You mean having all your url like site.com/shop instead of just site.com ? You can define base url under the backoffice, in system > configuration > web

Comment: Yes, but only for the catalog pages, not for the contact page for example, is there a (build in) way to do that? Thanks for the configuration location. I'll use that if there's no other (simple) way..

Comment: What I mean to say is, the site is not only a webshop, it also has general information pages, so in my perception, the shop is located in `/shop/**`, and general pages are not.